# How do I get the sum in one column for certain values in another vba excel

Tags: excel, vba, loops, sum

I am pretty new to VBA and I can't get my head wrapped around the following:

[image: Screenshot from table]

I would need the sum of `Accom Revenue Total` per `MarketSegment`.
These should be saved in a variable so that I can add them up with the sum of the same `MarketSegment` in another workbook.

Thank you in advance guys.

Comment: Consider using a Pivot Table.

Comment: @Michiel Bogaert did you try Pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, one solution could be to use the built in Excel's functions (worksheet's application) "=sumifs()". And if you want to sum several sheets you can create a sum of "=sumifs()".

> myVarFromWB1 = WorksheetFunction.sumifs(…)
>     myVarFromWB2 = WorksheetFunction.sumifs(…)
>     SumOfVar = myVarFromWB1 + myVarFromWB2

I hope that my answer helped you. Have a nice day.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response the only issue here is that this is a weekly report and that the amounts that have to be added up are not always the same. Also if I would do it with your code it would become quite a long code. Thank you anyway for the response.

Answer (score 0):

For this answer i use Sheet1 (inludes Primary data)

[image]

and Sheet 2 (includes Totals)

[image]

Try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim i As Long, j As Long, LR1 As Long, LR2 As Long

    Dim Segment As String

    Dim Total As Double

    Dim Exist As Boolean

    LR1 = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR1

        Exist = True
        Segment = Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value
        Total = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Sheet1.Range("B2:B" & LR1), Sheet1.Range("B" & i).Value, Sheet1.Range("D2:D" & LR1))

        LR2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        If LR2 = 1 Then
            Sheet2.Range("A2").Value = Segment
            Sheet2.Range("A2").Offset(0, 1).Value = Total
        Else
            LR2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            For j = 2 To LR2
                If Sheet2.Range("A" & j).Value <> Segment Then
                    Exist = False
                Else
                    Exist = True
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j

                If Exist = False Then
                    Sheet2.Range("A" & LR2 + 1).Value = Segment
                    Sheet2.Range("A" & LR2 + 1).Offset(0, 1).Value = Total
                End If
        End If

    Next i

End Sub
```